# Lenovo RAM switching

Tags: memory, installation, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo T500 laptop. For a few days I keep getting a blue screen of death. I've asked about the problem and I've been told that it's a RAM crash, and that I need to change the RAM.

How can I open the laptop and switch the RAM locations? If there's any photos to clarify the steps involved I will be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the "User Guides and Manuals" page for your computer.

http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/guides-and-manuals/default.page?

This is your specific "Hardware Maintenance Manual":

http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/43y6630_04.pdf

Go to page 83 of the manual, "Removing and replacing a FRU". Go to "1050 DIMM". It will tell you that you need the prerequisites of "1010 Battery Pack", and "1040 Palm Rest...".

The directions are excellent and contain very good diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

On [Lenovo](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-71314.html) website you have the full set of instruction (with images) of how to remove/install the RAM.

When you click in the provided link, it will tell you the website moved but ignore the message and all the instructions will appear.